# 400 Bad Request: Djoser built-in create user using django Signals

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have 3 models (including Custom User) structured:

**accounts.models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models #type: ignore
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField #type: ignore

# Create your models here.
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, user_role, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address.")

        if not user_role:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a user role.")
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_role=user_role, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, user_role="admin", password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_admin", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_admin") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_admin=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(email, user_role, password, **extra_fields)

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USER_ROLES = (
        ("resident", "Resident"),
        ("healthworker", "Health Worker"),
        ("admin", "Admin")
    )

    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    user_role = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=USER_ROLES)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["user_role",]

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user_role == "admin":
            self.is_staff = True
            self.is_admin = True
        elif self.user_role == "healthworker":
            self.is_staff = True
            self.is_admin = False
        else:
            self.is_staff = False
            self.is_admin = False
        
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class AddressDetails(models.Model):
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,)
    address_line_three = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,)
    barangay = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True,)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True,)
    
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ("F", "Female",),
        ("M", "Male",),
        ("U", "Unsure",),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(UserAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,)
    relationship_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50,)
    address_details = models.OneToOneField(AddressDetails, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I tried using POSTMAN to test the /users/ endpoint, In the requesting body contains all the fields from the 3 models. It causes a 400 Bad Request.

**accounts.serializers.py**

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
# from django.db import transaction
# from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
# from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from .models import AddressDetails, UserProfile

User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    address_line_one = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    address_line_two = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    address_line_three = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    province = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    barangay = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    city = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    zip_code = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    middle_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField(required=True)
    gender = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    relationship_status = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "email",
            "user_role",
            "password",
            "first_name",
            "middle_name",
            "last_name",
            "date_of_birth",
            "gender",
            "relationship_status",
            "phone_number"
            "address_line_one",
            "address_line_two",
            "address_line_three",
            "province",
            "barangay",
            "city",
            "zip_code",
        )
```

**accounts.views.py**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import UserCreateSerializer

# Create your views here.
@api_view(["POST"])
def register(request):
    serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.save(
            address_line_one = request.data["address_line_one"],
            address_line_two = request.data["address_line_two"],
            address_line_three = request.data["address_line_three"],
            province = request.data["province"],
            barangay = request.data["barangay"],
            city = request.data["city"],
            zip_code = request.data["zip_code"],
            first_name = request.data["first_name"],
            middle_name = request.data["middle_name"],
            last_name = request.data["last_name"],
            date_of_birth = request.data["date_of_birth"],
            gender = request.data["gender"],
            relationship_status = request.data["relationship_status"],
            phone_number = request.data["phone_number"]
        )

    return Response(status=201)
```

**accounts.signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import transaction
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import AddressDetails, UserProfile

User = get_user_model()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_address_and_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    Signal receiver to create AddressDetails and UserProfile instances
    after a User instance is saved.
    """
    if created:
        print("Created!")
        # Create AddressDetails instance
        address_details = AddressDetails.objects.create(
            address_line_one = kwargs.get("address_line_one", ""),
            address_line_two = kwargs.get("address_line_two", ""),
            address_line_three = kwargs.get("address_line_three", ""),
            province = kwargs.get("province"),
            barangay = kwargs.get("barangay"),
            city = kwargs.get("city"),
            zip_code = kwargs.get("zip_code")
            )

        # Create UserProfile instance
        UserProfile.objects.create(
            user = instance,
            first_name = kwargs.get("first_name"),
            middle_name = kwargs.get("middle_name"),
            last_name = kwargs.get("last_name"),
            date_of_birth = kwargs.get("date_of_birth"),
            gender = kwargs.get("gender"),
            relationship_status = kwargs.get("relationship_status"),
            phone_number = kwargs.get("phone_number"),
            address_details = address_details
            )
```

**accounts.apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

**config.settings.py**

```
"user_create": "accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer", # custom serializer
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you run `django` in console/terminal to see error messages? Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: yeah man, I run django in console the server is running locally for testing the error message says Bad Request: /api/v1/users/ "POST /api/v1/users/ HTTP/1.1" 400 29. I'm stuck here.

Comment: in many APIs `400` means you send wrong data - ie. you forgot `API_KEY` or `AUTH_TOKEN`. I don't see function for `/users/` in your code. You could use `print()` in this function to see which lines are executed - this way you can what can make problem. You may also run `django` in  `debug mode` to see more information.